# DocumentItem.SaveAs results in corrupted file

Tags: c#, file, outlook, outlook-addin

Within outlook I have various DocumentItems in folders such as the inbox and I am trying to save these to the file system within a drag/drop event.

Here is the code:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= _application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count; i++)
{
    var temp = _application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[i];

    var documentItem = (temp as DocumentItem);
    if (documentItem == null)
        continue;
    var tempFileName = Path.GetTempPath() + documentItem.Subject;
    documentItem.SaveAs(tempFileName);
}
```

They seem to save successfully and have file sizes:
[image]

But when I try to open any of them they all say they cannot be opened so they are corrupted somehow, does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling SaveAs without specifying the format, and Outlook Object Model defaults it to olMsg. You end up with an MSG file with a JPG extension.

What you need to do is loop though all attachments in the DocumentItem.Attachments collection and call Attachment.SaveAsFile. You might also want to use the Attachmeent.FileName property.

Just a general comment - multiple dot notation is evil, especially in a loo:

```
Selection selection = _application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
for (var i = 1; i <= selection.Count; i++)
{
   var temp = selection[i];
   var documentItem = (temp as DocumentItem);
   ...
```