# DocumentItem.SaveAs Saves the Document But as Corrupted File

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am writting an Outlook add in.  My application gets a reference to an item and saves it like this:

```
string myFileName = "A.docx";
if (myItem is DocumentItem)
{
   var docItem = myItem as DocumentItem;
   docItem.SaveAs(myFileName);
}
```

This will safe the word doc file "A.docx" to a temporary folder on my machine.

However, when I double click on the file to open it, I will get a popup telling me that the file is corrupt and cannot be opened.  Clicking OK on the popup offers to restore the file and if I choose do so, file is restored and opened.

This makes me believe that for some reason, the DocumentItem.SaveAs() is not working as expected and that it is saving the file in corrupted state.

Any idea what is wrong with the code above?

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION:**
I figured it out (thanks to this post [DocumentItem.SaveAs results in corrupted file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599752/documentitem-saveas-results-in-corrupted-file?rq=1)).  As the post does not explain exactly how to do it, I am posting my solution here just in case someone needs it.

Here is what I did following suggestion in the post above:

```
string myFileName = "A.docx";
if (myItem is DocumentItem)
{
   var docItem = myItem as DocumentItem;
   for (var i = 1; i <= docItem.Attachments.Count; i++)
   {
      var attachment = docItem.Attachments[i];
      attachment.SafeAsFile(myFileName);
   }
}
```

That solved the corruption issue.  Many thanks @DmitryStreblechenko

Comment: @DavidG It shows as "A.docx" file inside the folder where I save it.  So it has .docx extension.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out (thanks to this post DocumentItem.SaveAs results in corrupted file). As the post does not explain exactly how to do it, I am posting my solution here just in case someone needs it.

Here is what I did following suggestion in the post above:

```
string myFileName = "A.docx";
if (myItem is DocumentItem)
{
   var docItem = myItem as DocumentItem;
   for (var i = 1; i <= docItem.Attachments.Count; i++)
   {
      var attachment = docItem.Attachments[i];
      attachment.SafeAsFile(myFileName);
   }
}
```

That solved the corruption issue. Many thanks @DmitryStreblechenko

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [DocumentItem.SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868749.aspx):

> Saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the specified path and in the format of the specified file type. **If the file type is not specified, the MSG format (.msg) is used.**

So you should be using the extension `.msg` unless you specify the type. If you want to save as a Word Document format, you must specify the correct type from the [`OlSaveAsType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olsaveastype.aspx) enumeration. Note that the extension will be `.doc` if you specify `olDoc` like this:

```
string myFileName = "A.doc";
...
docItem.SaveAs(myFileName, OlSaveAsType.olDoc)
```

Comment: Yes, I read that but the file gets saved in my folder as "A.docx" file.

Comment: Well you are giving it a filename so of course it is. You could equally save it as `a.jpg` but that won't make it open in an image viewer.

Comment: @DavigG I figured it out, will update my post shortly in case other need it.  It is not an issue with the DocumentItem.SaveAs but with the fact that I am attepmting to save the document item instead of getting its attachment.

Comment: Just don't fundamentally change your question.